# URL redirected to index.html in pagespeed

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, web-vitals

When I submit my website (https://www.examplesite.com/) in pagespeed, it is automatically redirected to https://www.examplesite.com/public_html/index.html. What is the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had a redirection enabled for some countries and the Google Pagespeed server might be placed in any of those counties. That is why the redirection happens in Pagespeed result.

Answer (score 0):

it's depend on your web server to pointing the root.

```
    root /var/www/josuamarcelc.com;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
```

this is the example from NGINX web server, so when you access https://josuamarcelc.com, the server will try to access the files

```
/var/www/josuamarcelc.com/index
/var/www/josuamarcelc.com/index.php
/var/www/josuamarcelc.com/index.html
/var/www/josuamarcelc.com/index.htm
/var/www/josuamarcelc.com/index.nginx-debian.html
```